# C++ CreateWindow() function not defined

Tags: c++, winapi

I started playing around with the win32 api in c++ and as i was about to make a button, the intellisense says "define CreateWindow CreateWindowA". When i seem to hover down, it also says "Error: expected a )'".

Here is my code:

```
CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("You should press this button"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 50, 50, 300, 300, hWnd, (HMENU)somecrap, NULL, NULL);
```

So could you tell me what is exactly the problem? From searching the internet, people  were saying it has something to do with the character set with the preprocessor, but i'm not exactly sure what to do .

Comment: Please make the most minimal [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that gives you that error and point out exactly where that error occurs.

Comment: I wouldn't bother tracking down bugs that Intellisense tells you about, it's notoriously unreliable. Only believe what the compiler tells you.

Comment: Intellisense uses a different compiler frontend ([EDG](https://www.edg.com/index.php), I believe) from the actual compiler. This occasionally leads to Intellisense disagreeing with the compiler. It is safe to ignore Intellisense in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name `CreateWindow` is a macro. The real Win32 API functions are 2: `CreateWindowA` for ANSI and `CreateWindowW` for Unicode. Depending on `UNICODE` definition is used one of them.

Comment: It's evident from the post that `CreateWindow` is turned into `CreateWindowA`. It's not clear why a closing parenthesis would be expected in some unknown part of the OP's code.

Comment: @chris The title says that CreateWindow() function is not defined. I explain why pure `CreateWindow` does not exist.

Comment: Wow, thank you! i tried the w version  it worked.  This might be a stupid question, but could you point me towards the documentation where every function has it's equivalent of Unicode?

Comment: If what you say is true, then why is it that the same function works in "InitInstance" ?

Comment: Where is says that the function has a Unicode equivalent is in [the official MDSN documentation of the function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx).  Scroll down and it says: "Unicode and ANSI names  CreateWindowW (Unicode) and CreateWindowA (ANSI)".

Comment: @Unknownguy `InitInstance` does not have `TCHAR`, `TCHAR *` arguments or return value and for that reason there is no need from ANSI and Unicode versions. There is only `InitInstance` function. `A` and `W` versions exist for all Win32 functions which have string parameters or return value - by this way your project can be ready for ANSI and Unicode compilations. You have only to define or undef the `UNICODE` definition.

Comment: @i486 Nobody sets off today to support ANSI and Unicode. It's 2015.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It is correct. But ANSI versions still exist and in rare cases they are used.

Comment: Why do you want to use ANSI rather than Unicode? Why not simply target Unicode? Do you understand why TCHAR existed, and why it is now obsolete.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If I want to create very simple program or other which will process only ANSI strings, I prefer to disable UNICODE definition. Anyway, the answer here is to explain the particularity of Win32, not to argue is ANSI API still necessary.

Comment: @Unknownguy: `InitInstance` is not part of the Windows API. It is either a function you declared, or a framework (like MFC). The Unicode/ANSI translation is only relevant to the Windows API (for some definition of "relevant"). Unless you have to support Win9x it is best to leave this behind. Use `wchar_t` in place of `TCHAR`, an `L` prefix for string and character literals instead of `_T` or `TEXT` macros, and explicitly call the Unicode Windows API by appending a `W` suffix, if it is available.

Comment: @Dan The question and my answer do not recommend to use Unicode or not. The discussion is different.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There are plenty of reasons not to use the Unicode versions of these functions. If the software you're creating doesn't have any user front-end or international data, there's often no point in using characters that are twice as wide when single byte characters would have done exactly the same thing twice as fast and in half as much space. This answer gave me the info I was looking for, but could be citing the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @dan Actually if you call the ANSI version then the text is converted to utf16 and then passed to the native UTF16 API.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'll stop derailing the comments now, thanks for the info!